# How to read an arbitrary amount of lines from standard input using Scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm looking to scan standard input and write what is inputted into a file.

Currently, my code looks like this

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ShoppingList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            return;
        }

        String outputFile = args[0];

        try {
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            File fileOut = new File(outputFile);
            PrintWriter myWriter = new PrintWriter(fileOut);
            fileOut.createNewFile();

            while (true) {
                String nextLine = scanIn.nextLine();
                if (nextLine.equals("")) {
                    break;
                }
                myWriter.write(nextLine + "\n");
            }
            myWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException");
            return;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Currently, my code leaves a blank line between the end of the input stream and the end of the program. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDUeI.png) Is there any way to get rid of that line? Thanks!

Comment: If the stream ends, it should return a null. For System.in to end, the user should enter a control-d (Windows, and I think Linux) on the start of a line to end. It will end automatically if if in was redirected to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the newline (`\n`) to the end of the input when you write to file such as:

```
myWriter.write(nextLine + "\n");
```

Instead add it to the file **before** you add the User input string to file. Yes, this would add a blank line before the first User input line is written to file so you need a means to determine if a line has already been written to the file. There are a number of ways you can do this, a counter, a boolean flag, etc.

**Using a Boolean Flag:**

```
public class ShoppingList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            return;
        }

        String outputFile = args[0];

        try {
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            File fileOut = new File(outputFile);
            java.io.PrintWriter myWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(fileOut);
            fileOut.createNewFile();

            // Boolean Flag to determine if first line is written to file.
            boolean firstLineWritten = false; 

            while (true) {
                String nextLine = scanIn.nextLine().trim();
                if (nextLine.equals("")) {
                    // Nothing provided by User - Close the file.
                    break;
                }
                // If a first line has been written...
                if (firstLineWritten) {
                    // Add a system line separator to the file line previously written.
                    myWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
                }
                // Add User Input to file (no newline character added)
                myWriter.write(nextLine);
                // Write the User input to the file right away!
                myWriter.flush(); 
                // Flag the fact that the first line is written.
                firstLineWritten = true; 
            }
            myWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException");
        }
    }
}
```

**Using a Counter:**

```
public class ShoppingList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            return;
        }

        String outputFile = args[0];

        try {
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            File fileOut = new File(outputFile);
            java.io.PrintWriter myWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(fileOut);
            fileOut.createNewFile();

            // A counter to determine if first line is written to file. 
            int lineCounter = 0; 

            while (true) {
                String nextLine = scanIn.nextLine().trim();
                if (nextLine.equals("")) {
                    // Nothing provided by User - Close the file.
                    break;
                }
                // If a first line has been written...
                if (lineCounter > 0) {
                    // Add a system line separator to the file line previously written.
                    myWriter.write(System.lineSeparator());
                }
                // Add User Input to file (no newline character added)
                myWriter.write(nextLine);
                // Write the User input to the file right away!
                myWriter.flush(); 
                // Increment counter to the fact that the first line is written.
                lineCounter++; 
            }
            myWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException");
        }
    }
}
```